# How do we deploy the binary dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, binary, pom.xml, nexus

Let's say we have a simple Java project compiles into a simple.jar with its POM depends on log4j.jar. When I open the simple-1.0.jar, inside there is no log4j.jar. And then we upload this simple-1.0.jar onto Nexus.

Now when deploy this simple-1.0.jar to the target server, how do we deploy the log4j.jar?

Thanks
Jirong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either package the dependencies with your application (i.e. create an uber-jar, WAR, or EAR file) or you can deploy the dependent jars to a location on the server and then set that location as the classpath when you run the jar.

### Packaging an application as an Uber-JAR

One way of creating an uber-jar with Maven would be to use the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

### Deploying the dependent jars and setting classpath

In this scenario you would create a "libs" folder somewhere on the target machine and copy all of the dependent jars into this folder.

Then when you launch your application you would set the classpath like so:

```
java -classpath /{libs directory} -jar simple-1.0.jar
```

Multiple classpath entries can be specified by separating them with a `:` like also:

```
java -classpath /{directory1}:/{directory2} -jar simple-1.0.jar
```

You can have Maven list the resolved dependencies using the dependency plugin:

```
mvn dependency:list
```

Comment: Using the 2nd approach, how do we know what dependent jars to install during an automated deploy using tools like UrbanCode, Chef, Puppet?

Comment: That is the hard part and why you should package your application as an Uber-Jar instead.  You can view the dependencies with maven using the dependency plugin:   mvn dependency:list